# Sort varchar datatype with numeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

SQL SERVER 2005
SQL Sorting :

Datatype varchar

Should sort by

```
1.aaaa
5.xx
11.bbbbbb
12
15.
```

how can i get this sorting order

Wrong

```
1.aaaa
11.bbbbbb
12
15.
5.xx
```

Comment: A simple solution is to store `5.xx` as `005.xx`

Comment: Ah, the joys of alphanumeric sorting :-)

Comment: Another solution would be to store the numeric prefix and alpha suffix in separate columns of appropriate datatype.

Answer (score 1):

On Oracle, this would work.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
ORDER BY
  to_number(regexp_substr(COLUMN,'^[0-9]+')),
  regexp_substr(column,'\..*');
```

Comment: Why does this get downvoted? The OP didn't specify the DBMS. Also this gives an idea of what could be done.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - See the edit history. It originally suggested `ORDER BY to_number(column)` which would fail as the contents aren't entirely numeric.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well, it was since deleted, modified and then undeleted.

Comment: @all My original response was bad, since i misunderstood the question. So I've deleted it and tried to post a new one, but SO suggested that i should edit my old one instead, so i did that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by calculating a column based on what's on the left hand side of the period('.').

However this method will be very difficult to make robust enough to use in a production system, unless you can make a lot of assertions about the content of the strings.

Also handling strings without periods could cause some grief

```
with r as (
select '1.aaaa' as string
union select '5.xx'
union select '11.bbbbbb'
union select '12'
union select '15.' )

select *
from r
order by 
    CONVERT(int, left(r.string, case when ( CHARINDEX('.', r.string)-1 < 1) 
                                     then LEN(r.string) 
                                     else CHARINDEX('.', r.string)-1 end )), 
    r.string
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the entries have this form, you could split them into two parts and sort be these, for example like this:

```
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(fieldname, 1, CHARINDEX('.', fieldname))), 
    SUBSTRING(fieldname, CHARINDEX('.', fieldname) + 1, LEN(fieldname))
```

This should do a numeric sort on the part before the `.` and an alphanumeric sort for the part after the `.`, but may need some tuning, as I haven't actually tried it.

Another way (and faster) might be to create computed columns that contain the part before the `.` and after the `.` and sort by them.

A third way (if you can't create computed columns) could be to create a view over the table that has two additional columns with the respective parts of the field and then do the select on that view.